# How to filter out data that does not match in one category involving two conditions in R?

Tags: r, filter

Example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(GT = c('h', 'g', 't'), BD = c(1, 2, 3))
df2 <- data.frame(gt = c('h', 'g', 't'), bd = c(1, 2, 7))
```

I want to filter out all constructs that are different from one another with multiple conditions. For instance, in this case it'll be t and 3 vs. t and 7 that do not match.

`filter(df1, GT == df2, gt & df1, BD != df2, bd)` obviously doesn't work and I don't know other functions that'll filter out mismatches with multiple conditions present.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a reason not to, I would bind your data together with a `full_join` in `dplyr`, then you can use your `filter` to make sure `df1$BD` is the same as `df2$bd`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  full_join(df2, by = c("GT" = "gt")) %>% 
  filter(BD == bd)
```

Which gives:

```
  GT BD bd
1  h  1  1
2  g  2  2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Option 1
ind <- paste0(df1$GT, df1$BD) %in% paste0(df2$gt, df2$bd) 
df1[ind, ] # common elements
df2[ind, ]


df1[!ind, ] # different elements
df2[!ind, ]


# Option 2
merge(df1, df2, by.x=c("GT", "BD"), by.y = c("gt", "bd")) # common elements
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to easily visually distinguish the differences, use `diffObj`:

```
library(diffobj)
df1 <- data.frame(GT = c("h","g","t"), BD = c(1, 2, 3))
df2 <- data.frame(GT = c("h","g","t"), BD = c(1, 2, 7))
diffObj(df1,df2)
```

[image: diffobj]

This even works if your column names are different... it will just highlight that too:

```
df1 <- data.frame(GT = c("h","g","t"), BD = c(1, 2, 3))
df2 <- data.frame(gt = c("h","g","t"), bd = c(1, 2, 7))
diffObj(df1,df2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a primary key and then merge or use any filter between the match of those

```
df1$primary_key <- paste0(df1$GT,df1$BD)
df2$primary_key <- paste0(df2$gt,df2$bd)
new.df <- df1[which(df1$primary_key == df2$primary_key ),] #using which
new.df <- merge(df1, df2, by="primary_key")#using merge
```

It would depend on the real database how you manage to include subset or more filters, with more AND / OR logic.